# VS2010 - Strange Fuzzy Menu Behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I found something interesting today when opening VS2010 on my PC. It looked as if all the text had gone a bit fuzzy. It happens in particular in the menu bar after moving the mouse over the menu item the first time. Hopefully the pictures below can explain better than I...

[image]

Above is the menu bar with clear unblurred text.

[image]

Above, I have moved my mouse only over "Edit" and "View"

[image]

Finally, the above is after I moved my mouse over all menu items.

This is specific to VS2010 and has not occurred in the past. Even all the text on the "Start Page" is blurry (initially at start-up regardless of mouse movement).All other software on the PC (that I've seen) works normally.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

[image]

**Come to find out, it is also doing this in Visual Studio Express 2010, but not VS2008 (ie. only stuff with WPF UIs).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I resolved this in the most unusual way.

I had previously adjusted the anti-aliasing for my ATI 5850 graphics card under the "game performance" setting. Apparently this also screws with non-gaming WPF graphics.

Reverted the setting back to "Use application settings" and all is good.